# Where on with() relationship eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to paginate links from a page, but it returns the same links, the "where" don't works...

Controller:

```
public function page_load_more($last_id, $pid) {

    $page = Page::where('friendly_url', $pid)
                    ->select('id', 'photo', 'friendly_url', 'name')
                    ->with('ptag', 'get_following')
            ->with(['links' => function($query) use($last_id) {
                            $query->where('id', '<', $last_id);
                        }])
                    ->with(['links.comments.user' => function($query) {
                            $query->select('id', 'name', 'lastname', 'photo', 'friendly_url');
                        }])->first();

    return view('site.list.page.links', compact('page'));
}
```

JQuery:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(document).height() <= $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()) {
        var isLoading = false;
        var id = $('.link-shared:last-child').attr("rel");
        var p_id = $(".feed-page-info").attr("rel");

        if (isLoading === false) {
            var isLoading = true;
            $.ajax({
                url: window.location.origin + "/ajax/page/load_more/" + id + '/' + p_id,
                dataType: "HTML",
                beforeSend: function () {

                },
                success: function (response) {
                    $('.page-feed-insert').append(response);
                    var isLoading = false;
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Links showed:

> 1 2 3

Links when load more:

> 1 2 3

Answer (score 0):

Swap your where and with clauses and merge your `with`s together like:

```
Page::with(['ptag', 'get_following'])->select(...)->where(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [whereHas](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) method if you want to limit your results based on the  relationship condition (links.id > $last_id) :

```
Page::where('friendly_url', $pid)
    ->select('id', 'photo', 'friendly_url', 'name')
    ->whereHas('links', function($query) use ($last_id) {
        $query->where('links.id', '<', $last_id);
    })
    ->with(['ptag', 'get_following', 'links.comments.user' => function($query) {
        $query->select('id', 'name', 'lastname', 'photo', 'friendly_url');
    }])->first();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use whereHas that will work.

On with where will just not include the object from pivot table but still you will get the data.

Or if you want to apply where with relation you can use has('relation_name') or doest('relation_name')